# Escape characters in BQ external tables

Tags: google-bigquery, external-tables

I have an external table which is populated from a csv file.
In the csv file there is a field which has an escape character in it followed by a coma.
eg "a\,b" which should read just "a,b". when i load the csv file it it separates it into  2 columns "a", "b" but should read "a,b" in one column. I've tried using the option = '' without any luck.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL TABLE TEST

(A STRING,
 B STRING)
OPTIONS (
    format = 'CSV',
    quote = '\'
         )


Could someone help ?
```

Comment: how does csv look like ? `"a\,b","c"` or `a\,b,c` ?

Comment: hi it looks like this   the later   blah, a\,b  , blah

Comment: maybe there is another simple way but you may try below. hope it helps. In the answer, field_delimiter `CHR(1)` means to treat each line in a file as single column in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try below workaround.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL TABLE `your-project.your-dataset.so_test` (
  raw STRING
) OPTIONS (
  uris=['gs://your-bucket/so/test2.csv'],
  format = 'CSV',
  field_delimiter = CHR(1)
);

CREATE TEMP TABLE sample_table AS
SELECT csv[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] col1,
       REPLACE(csv[SAFE_OFFSET(1)], '|', ',') col2,
       csv[SAFE_OFFSET(2)] col3,
  FROM `bigdata-cubig-data.bdc_cubig_temp.so_test`, 
UNNEST ([STRUCT(SPLIT(REPLACE(raw, '\\,', '|')) AS csv)]);

SELECT * FROM sample_table;
```

**Sample csv file**

- gs://your-bucket/so/test2.csv

> blah,a\,b,blah

**Query results**

[image]

Or, using *PIVOT* query

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE sample_table (
  col1 STRING, col2 STRING, col3 STRING,
) AS
SELECT * REPLACE(REPLACE(col_1, '|', ',') AS col_1) FROM (
  SELECT col, offset
    FROM `your-project.your-dataset.so_test`,
  UNNEST (SPLIT(REPLACE(csv, '\\,', '|'))) col WITH offset
) PIVOT (ANY_VALUE(col) col FOR offset IN (0, 1, 2));

SELECT * FROM sample_table;
```